# Programatically retrieve units from a map's SpatialReference

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to retrieve the units (like feet or meters) of the current spatial reference from an ArcGIS map, using the JavaScript API.

I have the map's spatial reference object, with it's well-known ID.  I'm guessing there would be a lookup function or something I could use to get the units for that spatial reference, but I can't find one.

Does such a function exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the WKT (Well-Known Text)?  If so, you may be able to brute force parse looking for "UNIT".

EDIT:

Here's a hack for you.  You can retrieve the WKT from a WKID by going to this address:

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/{wkid}/esriwkt/

For example, http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2283/esriwkt/ returns:

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / Virginia North (ftUS)",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",39.2],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",38.03333333333333],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",37.66666666666666],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-78.5],PARAMETER["false_easting",11482916.667],PARAMETER["false_northing",6561666.667],UNIT["Foot_US",0.30480060960121924]]
```

You can parse that up.

There are other formats available if you go up a level.  See if any other would be easier for you.

Comment: No, I don't have it, just the WKID.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Spatial Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/spatialreference-amd.html) class on the API?  This has a `isWebMercator()` method.  Can you explain what you mean by "units"?

Comment: I mean units like meters or feet (or degrees).